# Ordering an array of 8bit numbers - Assembly 8085

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, numbers

I am given an array of size X, and I'm supposed to order it on ascending order.
The array is saved on memory, same goes for the size. I'm also supposed to save the numbers on the memory (example: 0050 - 4 ; 0051 - 3  after the program must become 0050 - 3; 0051 - 4)

I'm having trouble doing this, since my teacher wasn't that great and we just had about 3 hours of Assembly. 
Can anyone help me with the machine code of de problem?
I know how to compare the 2 numbers, just having trouble understanding how to save them on their new positions and continue checking for the entire array.

Sorry if the English was bad or I couldn't express myself.
Thanks in advance, 
Mário

Comment: Just implement a simple sort algorithm, like [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) - all you need is a loop and the ability to compare and swap numbers.

Comment: Curious microprocessor choice for teaching assembly language. Are you sure you aren't targeting the 8086? Admittedly a needlessly convoluted architecture, but still..

Comment: @doynax: this is very common in some parts of the world, such as the Indian subcontinent - they are still teaching a computing syllabus from the 1980s: 16 bit DOS, Turbo C, 8085, 8086, etc.

Comment: @PaulR: More like the 1970s in the case of the 8085. Stuck on an ancient CPM system presumably. At least 16-bit 8086 code was supported through DOS emulation on modern Windows systems up until fairly recently

Answer (score 2):

The following is my attempt at transcribing the simplest-possible bubble sort implementation to the 8080/8085 assembly language.

First of a C implementation somewhat adapted to the 8080's pointer limitations to serve as reference:

```
int list[N];
bool out_of_order;

void sort(void) {
    do {
        int *ptr = list;
        int len = N - 1;
        out_of_order = 0;
        do {
            int first, second;
            first = *ptr;
            ++ptr;
            second = *ptr;
            if(first > second) {
                --ptr;
                *ptr = second;
                ++ptr;
                *ptr = first;
                out_of_order = 1;
            }
            --len;
        } while(len);
    } while(out_of_order);
}
```

And now for the assembly code. Bear with me, I'm used to Z80 syntax.

```
sort:   LXI  BC,list    ;ptr = list
        MVI  D,N-1      ;len = N-1
        MVI  E,0        ;out_of_order = 0
inner:  LDAX BC         ;first = *ptr
        MOV  H,A
        INX             ;++ptr
        LDAX BC         ;second = *ptr
        CMP  H          ;if(first > second)
        JNC  noswap 
        DCX  BC         ;--ptr
        STAX BC         ;*ptr = second
        INX  BC         ;++ptr
        MOV  A,H        ;*ptr = first
        STAX BC
        LDI  E,1        ;out_of_order = 1
noswap: DCR  D          ;--len
        JNZ  inner      ;while(len)
        DCX  E          ;while(out_of_order)
        JP   sort
        RET
```

Note that the unlike the C version this only compares unsigned 8-bit integers since the 8080 struggles with 16-bit arithmetic and lacks an overflow flag. Oh, and I'm not *quite* bored enough to dig out an assembler and emulator so this is all entirely untested.